# How to add data to Google calendar programmatically in android?

Tags: android

Hi I need to add particulars to Google calendar from my application. Is it possible to add data to Google calendar? I am new to android Help me to solve this.

Comment: Are you referring to the Google Calender web application or the Calender app on the device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using these apis (GData) you can access all Google services, including Calendar:
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/wiki/Version2

Answer (score 18):

I realize that this is an old thread, but for people that stumble upon it now, please note that [Google Data Java Client Library](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/)  (or gdata-java-client) is no longer being actively developed.

You should use the [Google API Client Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client) for Java that has full support for Android.

It has [Google Calendar Sample applications](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/GoogleAPIs) for Android. (One using ClientLogin using the Android accountmanager, and one using the more secure OAuth for authentication/authorization.

(Google doesn't recommend using ClientLogin as it's considered insecure)

Answer (score 1):

if you want another aproach   you can check this
http://www.developer.com/ws/article.php/3850276/Working-with-the-Android-Calendar.htm
keep in mind you need to have a real android device to debug .Emulator doesn't come with calendar so the URI cannot be served

Answer (score 1):

till now gdata not available for android.

> http://code.google.com/p/android-gdata/

You can add event and calendar in the widget. But it removes the added calendar when sync with the Google account.

Till now no proper solution is available.

Comment: i have also try the above mention link by weakwire

http://www.developer.com/ws/article.php/3850276/Working-with-the-Android-Calendar.htm
It is possible to add calendar and events programmatically in the android Calendar widget. The application is syncing Events with the Google account. But not syncing the programmatically inserted calendar and deleting it from the widget. It is also noted that the Calendar widget has also no option to add new calendar.