# Connect to Google Calendar service using Android's user Google Credentials

Tags: java, android, google-calendar-api, gdata-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add data to Google calendar programmatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948900/how-to-add-data-to-google-calendar-programmatically-in-android)

I am developing an App on Android 2.3.3 that connects to Google Calendar using the GData API in Java. I want to use the devices Google Credentials to connect to the Calendar Service. The only way I know so far to connect to Calendar Service is by setting the username and password credentials. But, as far as I know, that information is not available in Android.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Mikywan.