# How to access google calender from Android?

Tags: android, calendar

I am trying to use google api / gdata to access calendar. It worked fine while playing with standard Java. But I have started getting

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gdata.client.calendar.CalendarService`

as soon as I call,

```
CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("My Application");
```

when I was trying to use it on Android. What am I missing? 
Thanks much, in advance...

Answer (score 1):

To access Calendar APIs from Android, it is recommended to use the [Google APIs Client Library for Java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/)

You can check out the [android samples](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/calendar-v2-atom-android-sample/src/com/google/api/client/sample/calendar/android/CalendarAndroidSample.java?repo=samples)

It appears that using gdata api from android is no longer being developed.

see [How to add data to Google calendar programmatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948900/how-to-add-data-to-google-calendar-programmatically-in-android/2948959#2948959) for more discussion.